# Erlang: How to get unique pairs from the list faster?

Tags: performance, erlang

I have a list with pairs `[[1, 2], [2, 1], [1, 3] ..]`. How to get unique pairs in the fastest way? I have a written a function, but it's too slow.

```
-module(test).
-export([unique/1, unique/2, pairs/1]).

unique(L) -> unique(L, []).
unique([], UL) -> UL;
% L: list of lists
unique(L, UL) ->
    [X,Y] = hd(L),
    case lists:member([Y,X], L) of
        true ->
            unique(L--[[Y,X]], [[X,Y]|UL]);
        false ->
            unique(tl(L), UL)
    end.

pairs(L) -> [[X,Y] || X <- L, Y <- L, X=/=Y].
```

From the shell,

```
1> test:pairs([1,2,3]).
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]]
2> test:unique(test:pairs)). %Very slow for large list. How to improve?
[[2,3],[1,3],[1,2]]
```

I have a list of pairs with list length `9900` of which half is duplicate. I am using the pairs list for further computation. With the original list (with duplicate pairs), the time is `3.718s`, and if I filter out unique list and use if for computation, the time is `7.375s` which is worse.

I changed the function to not use `--` operator.

```
unique(L, UL) ->
    [X,Y] = hd(L),
    case lists:member([Y,X], L) of
        true ->
            unique(tl(L), [[Y,X]|UL]);
        false ->
            unique(tl(L), UL)
    end.
```

Even so it gives a mere `0.047s` improvement at `7.375s`, which points that the algorithm is not fast enough.

Could you please point out any better algorithm? Are there any built-in library functions for this?
Thanks.

Comment: A better algorithm would use a hash table or BST as the accumulator in `unique`: by using a list, you've got a quadratic time algorithm.

Comment: Can you replace the original list with a more efficient data structure such as a set or a balanced search tree.  Either could naturally identify duplicates as it was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try `lists:usort([lists:sort(X) || X <- L])`, I tried it with a 9900 element list and it is less than 1 sec.

```
18> F = fun(X,L) -> [[X,Y] || Y <- L] end.                     
#Fun<erl_eval.12.82930912>
19> L = lists:seq(1,100).                                      
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
 23,24,25,26,27,28,29|...]
20> L1 = lists:foldl(fun(X,Acc) -> F(X,lists:delete(X,L)) ++ Acc end,[],L).                                                                  
[[100,1],
 [100,2],
 [100|...],
 [...]|...]
21> length(L1).                                                
9900                                                                            
22> io:format("~p~n",[erlang:now()]),lists:usort([lists:sort(X) || X <- L1]),io:format("~p~n",[erlang:now()]).                                 
{1383,395086,328000}
{1383,395086,515000}
ok
23> lists:usort([lists:sort(X) || X <- [[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]]]).                                                                
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
24>
```

shows that the execution time is less than 0.2 sec, the command on line 23 tests it works.

Comment: +1 Wow, nice idea. Sorting the inner list and using `usort` is faster at `2.562s` (overall time including the rest of the program).

Comment: There is no need to do a pre-sort before passing the list into `lists:usort`.

Comment: It's a list of lists. `lists:usort([[1,2], [3,4], [2,1]]).` gives `[[1,2],[2,1],[3,4]]`. Oh, I understand, the given list gets sorted, but only one pair is required, so the list the pre-sorted.

Comment: Depending on the size that can have your first list, maybe another algorithm than usort will be faster. I'll make a little evaluation of the complexity of each solution with various length of list. Another possibility is to directly generate the list without redundant values (if it makes sense in your application) `pairs(L) -> [[X,Y] || X <- L, Y <- L, X>Y].`

Comment: This works as well. The lowest time is `1.437` and the average for 5 runs is `1.453`.

Comment: I will accept this answer as this method produces the lowest time.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do it. `v1` is fastest but most dirty way:

```
-module(uniq).

-export([v1/1, v2/1, v3/1, v4/1, gen/1]).

-compile({inline, [s/1]}).

s([X, Y]) when X > Y -> [Y, X];
s(L) -> L.

v1(L) ->
  erase(),
  [put(s(K), ok) || K <- L],
  [K || {K, _} <- erase() ].

v2(L) ->
  sets:to_list(sets:from_list([s(K) || K <- L])).

v3(L) ->
  T = ets:new(set, [private, set]),
  ets:insert(T, [{s(K)} || K <- L]),
  R = [K || {K} <- ets:tab2list(T)],
  ets:delete(T),
  R.

v4(L) ->
  lists:usort([s(K) || K <- L]).

gen(N) ->
  [[random:uniform(100), random:uniform(100)] || _ <- lists:seq(1, N)].
```

Result speed:

```
1> L = uniq:gen(1000000).
...
2> [ element(1, timer:tc(uniq,Alg,[L]))/1000000 || Alg <- [v1, v2, v3, v4]].
[0.243595,1.042272,0.35633,1.309971]
3> [ element(1, timer:tc(uniq,Alg,[L]))/1000000 || Alg <- [v1, v2, v3, v4]].
[0.236856,1.000818,0.359761,1.309743]
4> [ element(1, timer:tc(uniq,Alg,[L]))/1000000 || Alg <- [v1, v2, v3, v4]].
[0.242901,1.039107,0.357476,1.30691]
```

Note `lists:usort/1` version `v4` is the slowest one. Using process dictionary in version `v1` is very dirty thing and you should avoid it but in special cases it is doable. Using `ets` in version `v3` has good performance and you should use this version for any serious work. For smaller lists is also `sets` version `v2` good option. It is brief and pretty good.

The trick to avoid processor dictionary pollution and still having same performance is using sub-process:

```
v1(L) ->
  Self = self(),
  PID = spawn_link(fun() ->
          [put(s(K), ok) || K <- L],
          Self ! {result, self(), [K || {K, _} <- erase() ]}
      end),
  receive
    {result, PID, Result} -> Result
  after 10000 -> error(timout)
  end.
```

You will lost some performance by copying data in and out to separate heap (unless you use binary) but it can be still fastest option. In this case it takes more about 50ms so still the fastest.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the various approaches. I have tried all the algorithms and the fastest among them is `v2`. However the `usort` from Pascal's answer is slightly faster. I didn't try with sub-processes though. Will look into it later. In your example the generated list `gen/1` does not create pairs like [a,b], [b,a]. Time for the whole program: `v1: 2.781`, `v2: 2.687`, `v3: 2.906`, `v4: 2.750`. `usort_pascal: 2.532`, `my_initial_version: 7.172`, `not_using_unique_at_all: 3.703`.

Comment: I am running the program using `escript`. So not sure whether the compile inline take effect. The `s/1` function and the way the sorted list is generated using comprehension is cool.

Comment: I have added `v5(L)->lists:usort([lists:sort(X) || X <- L]).` and ran from the shell with list `L=[[X,Y] || X<-lists:seq(1,500), Y<-lists:seq(1,500), X=/=Y].` giving `[0.5,5.735,0.781,0.594,0.593]` in which `v1` is the fastest and then `v5` and `v4`, by very slight margin. Any idea why it is different when running using `escript`?

Comment: @kadaj: Unless you use `-mode(compile).` in your escript it is not compiled at all but interpreted. Interpreted code can have very different performance from compiled one.

Comment: With `-mode(compile)`, the lowest time obtained when ran multiple times are as follows. `v1: 1.469`, `v2: 1.515`, `v3: 1.484`, `v4: 1.453`, `usort: 1.468`, `initial_version: 4.469`, `not_using_unique_at_all: 1.453`. Ran 5 times and considering the average the time respectively are: `1.472`, `1.568`, `1.496`, `1.493`, `1.484`, `4.478`, `1.509`. Here `v1` is fastest.

Comment: The different approaches listed helps me with learning Erlang. If only SO had ways to accept multiple answers. Thanks.